# Mockito, object is not mocked

Tags: java, mockito

Here is the simple class I test. It looks strange but I have oversimplified it for a reason.

```
public class DishService {

    DaoFactory daoFactory = DaoFactory.getInstance();

    public void exampleMethod() {
        System.out.println(daoFactory);
     DishDao dishDao = daoFactory.createDishDao();
        System.out.println(dishDao.findById(1));
    }
}
```

And here is the DaoFactory class

```
public abstract class DaoFactory {
    private static DaoFactory daoFactory;

    public abstract UserDao createUserDao();

    public abstract DishDao createDishDao();

    public abstract OrderDao createOrderDao();

    public static DaoFactory getInstance() {
        if (daoFactory == null) {
            synchronized (DaoFactory.class) {
                daoFactory = new JDBCDaoFactory();

            }
        }
        return daoFactory;
    }
}
```

And here is my test class

```
  @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
     class DishServiceTest {
        @Spy
        DishService dishService;
        @Mock
        DishDao dishDao;
        @Mock
        DaoFactory daoFactory;
    
        @Test
        void example() {
            MockedStatic<DaoFactory> daoFactoryDummy = Mockito.mockStatic(DaoFactory.class);
            daoFactoryDummy.when(DaoFactory::getInstance).thenReturn(daoFactory);
            Mockito.when(daoFactory.createDishDao()).thenReturn(dishDao);
            when(dishDao.findById(1)).thenReturn(new Dish());
            dishService.exampleMethod();
        }
```

The problem is that daoFactory simply is not mocked. As you can see, I return new Dish ( default constructor ), so `System.out.println()` should show an empty object but it connects to DB and fetch object from real daoFactory.
And here is what I see in console

Dish{name='dadawd', description='wdadwad2', category=DRINKS, price=23131.00, imageFileName='FIRSTSnacksAsDaypart_1.jpg', orderItems=null}

Unnecessary stubbings detected.

1. -> at service.DishServiceTest.example(DishServiceTest.java:35)
2. -> at service.DishServiceTest.example(DishServiceTest.java:36)
   35 and 36 lines of code you can see at the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At which point do you initialize/create dishService object? In the @BeforeTest?
Since you have a field `daoFactory` on `dishService` object, `DaoFactory.getInstance()` gets called before you mock its methods, as it is called when you create `dishService` object.

So you need to create dishService object **after** you have mocked the Factory static methods, inside @Test method.

Or another way would be to use `DaoFactory.getInstance()` directly in the `dishService.exampleMethod()`.

In both cases: first mock static method, then call it.

Also don't forget to close static mock, or even better: use it inside try-with-resources construct.